# selenium chrome commandprompt

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Public Class Form1

Dim service As ChromeDriverService =ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService      



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim chromeOptions As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("ignore-certifcate-errors")
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("test-type")
    chromeOptions.AddArguments("HideCommandPromptWindow")
    Dim driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

the above works as I need, but it also brings up an annoying command prompt
How do I stop the command prompt appearing?

Comment: Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
        Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        Dim driver1 = New ChromeDriver(driverService, New ChromeOptions())
        driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com")
        driver1.Manage().Window().Size = New Size(900, 500)

Comment: the code above works correct and no prompt